# How to return an empty value in golang?

Tags: function, go, return-value

I need to return an empty value for a function in golang, my code look something like this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    for i:=0;i<6;i++{
        x,e := test(i)
        fmt.Println(i,x,e)
    }


}

func test(i int)(r int,err error){
    if i%2==0{
        return i,nil
    }else{
        return 
    }
}
```

and its output

> ```
> 0 0 <nil>
> 1 0 <nil>
> 2 2 <nil>
> 3 0 <nil>
> 4 4 <nil>
> 5 0 <nil>
> ```

whereas I want this type of output

> ```
> 0 0 <nil>
> 1 <nil> <nil>
> 2 2 <nil>
> 3 <nil> <nil>
> 4 4 <nil>
> 5 <nil> <nil>
> ```

How to return empty value in golang?

Comment: Return empty interface then

Comment: You can pass the pointer instead of value `func test(i *int)(r *int,err error)`

Comment: You cannot. There are no "empty" values in Go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Empty value" is a matter of convention. You have to define what empty value means.

- Many of the standard library functions return an invalid value to denote empty. For instance, `strings.Index` returns -1, because all valid values are >=0
- Functions returning pointer usually return `nil`
- There are functions that return pairs of values, one value and one denoting validity. Maps and channels also use this convention:

```
value, exists:=someMap[key]
```

Above, if `exists` is true, then `value` has a valid value. If `exists` is `false`, `value` is not valid (empty).

- Many functions return a value and error. If error is non-nil, the value is meaningless.

So in your code, you can do:

```
func test(i int)(r int,valid bool){
    if i%2==0{
        return i,true
    }else{
        return 0,false
    }
}
```

Or, if you have an error condition, return a non-nil error from your function and check if there is an error where you called it. If there is an error, whatever the value returned is "empty".